# Encode data into user-typed code, like an old game's password-save system

Tags: java, cryptography, java1.4, human-readable

I tried searching for information on this, but must not know the right terms to use...

What would be the simplest way to store information in a human-readable and -writeable passcode, with enough padding to make randomly guessed codes unlikely to be valid? Not unlike 8-bit console games' password-save systems.

In my particular case, I'd like to be able to encode three unsigned integers (with a maximum length of probably about 20 bits each) into a passcode under Java 1.4.2, and decrypt them on a web server. I was thinking about also adding a random or date-based value in an attempt to make passcodes unique.

The code could use numbers, mixed-case letters and potentially some simple symbols, but should probably exclude easily-confused characters like 1lI and O0. Since the user needs to type it, obviously shorter is better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose the alphabet that you want to use. It can have as many symbols as you like, in any order. An example alphabet would be `ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789` which contains 34 symbols.
2. Encode the data you want to save as a single integer by using bitshifts and bitwise or, or multiplication and addition. This shouldn't be a problem if you have about 20 bits of data as you say.
3. Encode the integer from step 1 in base-N, where N is the number of symbols in your alphabet, then print it using symbols from the alphabet.
4. Add a "check digit" on the end. Adding all of the output digits mod N is a simple and useful system. A check digit isn't real crypto and won't stop anyone who's putting any *effort* into forging a save code, but it limits the chances of a randomly chosen code working. If your alphabet has 34 symbols then there's only a 1-in-34 chance of the check digit matching on a random code.
5. To decode, first validate the check digit in the received code, then decode the base-N representation (reverse step 3), then extract the individual values from the integer value (reverse step 2).

The number of symbols needed to represent `k` bits of data in base `n` plus one check digit is `ceil(k * log(2) / log(n)) + 1`, which is only 5 for `k`=20 bits and `n`=34.

Comment: Just clarifying, it would be about 60 bits in total (three 20-bit numbers). - Thanks! I guess this is almost a separate question, so no need to answer if you don't want to, but do you know of any simple way to obfuscate the passcode without changing its length, or where I could find information on the sort of algorithms that would be suitable for something like this?

Comment: Actually, I guess some transposition might be good enough. This isn't a high-security project.

Comment: I'd use 32 characters. Then each encodes 5 bits, which divides your 20 bit numbers evenly.

Answer (score -1):

You can encode your properties as Base64. The only restriction is that you must have a fixed size of your properties. You may want to apply MD5 algorithm or similar to the encoded string.

Take a look at this snipplet using [apache commons codec for java 1.4](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/commons-codec-1.4-bin.zip)

```
public class Base64Encoder {

/**
 * Base64 game properties encoded
 * @param properties list of properties as Strings
 * @return base64 encoded properties
 */
public String encodeProperties(List properties){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator iter = properties.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        buffer.append(iter.next().toString());
    }
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(buffer.toString().getBytes());
}

/**
 * Decodes a based64 properties
 * @param propertiesSize list of Integer with each property size
 * @param encodedProperties base64 encoded properties
 * @return List of properties as String
 */
public List decodeProperties(List propertiesSize, String encodedProperties){
    List decodedProperties = new ArrayList();
    Iterator iter = propertiesSize.iterator();
    String decoded = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedProperties.getBytes()));
    int current = 0;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Integer propertySize = new Integer(iter.next().toString());
        String property = decoded.substring(current, current + propertySize.intValue());
        decodedProperties.add(property);
        current += propertySize.intValue();
    }
    return decodedProperties;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String points = "1450";
    String level = "12";
    String lifes = "2";
    Base64Encoder encoder = new Base64Encoder();
    List properties = new ArrayList();
    properties.add(points);
    properties.add(level);
    properties.add(lifes);
    String encodedProperties = encoder.encodeProperties(properties); //MTQ1MDEyMg==
    System.out.println(encodedProperties);
    List propertiesSize =  new ArrayList();
    propertiesSize.add(Integer.valueOf(points.length()));
    propertiesSize.add(Integer.valueOf(level.length()));
    propertiesSize.add(Integer.valueOf(lifes.length()));
    System.out.println(encoder.decodeProperties(propertiesSize, encodedProperties)); //[1450, 12, 2]
}
```

}

Comment: Would the downvoter be able to comment on why they would not recommend this? Thanks!